# How to show view of WindowManager over navigation bar and status bar?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-windowmanager, android-statusbar, android-navigation-bar

I wanted to show a view (like sidebar) above/over status bar and navigation bar

I used this Flag in params

```
param = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            0,
            0,
            Comman.getPhoneTypeFlag(),
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS or
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE ,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT)
```

but the view is behind status bar and navigation buttons.
(NOTE: View is not fullscreen view it's a view like sidebar having wrap content height width)